# Does my camera still work?

Tags: old-cameras, kodak

I’ve left my camera untouched for years. as soon as i found it i order the charger online. i am currently charging it but it is not turning on. does it still work? ( it is an older kodak — easyshare c180)

Comment: There is no charger for this camera. There is no way to charge the camera. You can only replace the AA batteries. Please explain what you bought online and how you are using it.

Comment: Voted to close as the OP believes they can plug in the camera to “charge” it, and believes they should be able to turn it on while “charging” it. This camera only takes AA batteries and “charging” it is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

The camera itself would likely work, but after years of neglect the battery likely self-discharged to death and won't hold a charge. Some advanced chargers could manage to resuscitate it, but don't hold your breath.

This camera takes standard AA batteries, so you can test it with a pair of disposable alkaline AA batteries. If it works that way you will be able to replace the disposable AA batteries by fresh chargeable NiMH ones (very easy to find).